# PHP redirect_to not working

Tags: php

I am having an issue with PHP redirect_to. I have a form where a user can select an image to upload. Upon succussful upload I'd like the user to be redirected to a page that lists all images in the database. The following code comes from a PHP file called upload_image.php. It is in the same directory as the page I'd like to redirect to, list_images.php. I've narrowed down the problem area to the following code:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$image = new Image();     //User defined class
$image->caption = $_POST['caption'];     //Places caption text field in the database
$image->attach_file($_FILES['file_upload']);     //Copies image to images folder

if($image->save()){
    //Success
    $session->message("Image uploaded successfully!");
    redirect_to('list_images.php');    //PROBLEM AREA. Page never redirects.
}else{
    //Failure
    $message = join("<br />", $image->errors);
}}
```

My function for redirect_to() is the following:

```
    function redirect_to($location = NULL){
if($location != NULL){
    header("Location: {$location}");
    exit;
}}
```

The uploaded image is always successfully copied to the correct location and its information gets stored in the database. After submitting however I am always left with a blank page and the url of upload_image.php in the browser. Through countless echo tests I've determined that the problem happens at redirect_to('list_images.php'); I am able to echo text onto the blank page just before redirect_to, but anything after redirect_to does not get executed.

Does anyone have any ideas to advice?

Thank you!

Comment: `redirect_to` [is not a stock PHP function](http://www.php.net/manual-lookup.php?pattern=redirect_to&lang=en&scope=404quickref), so you'll need to provide its source code for us to have any chance of helping you.

Comment: `redirect_to();` is not a native PHP function. Please provide its definition.

Comment: redirect_to is not a native php function so please include your code.

Comment: "I am always left with a blank page [...] Through countless echo tests"... you know you could've just [set the errorlevel](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php), right?

Comment: You will not be able to output or do anything after a call to `exit()`, if this is what you mean.. Anyway, the redirect should occur when setting `header("Location: ..")`, so there's another problem..

Answer (score 2):

The way to redirect would be:

```
header("Location: list_images.php");
exit();
```

Comment: You're missing the HTTP response body to match HTTP specs.

Comment: @hakre: a 302 is sent if not set manually. Shouldn't that be enough?

Comment: Specs require you send a response body telling the new location as well, a header alone is not enough. It's a common mistake made, only sending a location header and the 3xx status code.

Comment: @chelmetz: thanks for add "exit". I was only showing the actual redirect line. @hakre: nothing else is required: PHP will send 302 automatically if `location` header is present and no status is specified; and body of the response is not required for 302 responses.  Not sure about formal RFC, however we've used this technique for years with no problem in any browser.

Comment: *"The temporary URI SHOULD be given by the Location field in the response. Unless the request method was HEAD, the entity of the response SHOULD contain a short hypertext note with a hyperlink to the new URI(s)."* [REF](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) - If you have problems to understand SHOULD, there is a RFC which explains how to read it: http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2119.txt - It's the formal spec and the reason is that UAs must not automatically redirect. It's more a user issue (the person using the browser) than a browser issue.

Comment: @hakre: this is from RFC 2616 (http/1.1): "Unless the request method was HEAD, the entity of the response *SHOULD* contain a short hypertext note with a hyperlink to the new URI(s)."  SHOULD does not mean MUST - it's still optional from the point of view of the specifications.

Comment: Always doing obviously isn't matching: *"3. SHOULD   This word, or the adjective "RECOMMENDED", mean that there
   may exist valid reasons in particular circumstances to ignore a
   particular item, but the full implications must be understood and
   carefully weighed before choosing a different course."* - so for a general suggestion as an answer in this forum, you should not ignore this unless you know about the very specific requirements by the OP.

Answer (score 0):

```
header("Location: {$location}");
```

That's not a valid header I think. Try removing the "{}" braces.

Comment: The {} braces just delimit the variable name inside the string (it is the same of `${location}`). This is needed in cases like `"${foo}_bar"`, but it is a good practice to always use it to keep things clear

Comment: Removing braces didn't help. Still no redirect. Thank you for your suggestion however.

Comment: @redShadow: I didn't know that it also works if the opening brace is in front of the dollar sign. thanks.

Comment: @Bluewind, yes, it is awful, doesn't always work as expected (`{$aaa[123]}` - or similar - doesn't work if I remember correctly) but yes, it is allowed

Answer (score 0):

You should make your function really doing the job (and not optional). Additionally if you actually output the suggested HTTP response body, you would actually see if the function was called (or not):

```
function redirect_to($location)
{
    if (!headers_sent($file, $line))
    {
        header("Location: " . $location);
    } else {
        printf("<script>location.href='%s';</script>", urlencode($location));
        # or deal with the problem
    }
    printf('<a href="%s">Moved</a>', urlencode($location));
    exit;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Correct redirect function is defined below:

```
function redirect_url($path)
{
  header("location:".$path);
  exit;
}
```

For more information check this :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13539752/redirect-function/13539808